# symfony2: multiple entities one form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have 2 entities:

```
ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Link:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\LinkRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    dateAdded:
        type: datetime
    expirationDate:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
    designator:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: false
        unique: true
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
        unique: true
manyToOne:
    company:
        targetEntity: ADS\UserBundle\Entity\Company
        inversedBy: link
        joinColumn:
            name: company_id
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: true
    createdBy:
        targetEntity: ADS\UserBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: link
        joinColumn:
            name: createdBy_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    domain:
        targetEntity: ADS\DomainBundle\Entity\Domain
        inversedBy: link
        joinColumn:
            name: domain_id
            referencedColumnNames: id
oneToMany:
        paths:
            targetEntity: ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Path
            mappedBy: link
            cascade: [persist]
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

and

```
ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Path:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\PathRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    pathAddress:
        type: string
        length: 255
    pathWeight:
        type: string
        length: 255
manyToOne:
    link:
        targetEntity: ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Link
        inversedBy: paths
        joinColumn:
            name: link_id
            referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I have everything figured out except for the paths portion of the entity.  This is for an A/B split test, so each link can have 2 paths.  Each path will consist of a web address, and a number ( 0 - 100 )

Here is my form in it's current state:

```
<?php
namespace ADS\LinkBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PathType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('pathAddress')
        ->add('pathWeight')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Path'));
}
public function getName() { return 'ads_linkbundle_link'; }
}
```

and

```
<?php
namespace ADS\LinkBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

    class LinkType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('designator')
        ->add('domain', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ADS\DomainBundle\Entity\Domain',
            'property' => 'domainAddress'
        ))
        ->add('paths', 'collection', array('type' => new PathType(), 'allow_add' => true))
        ->add('Submit', 'submit')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Link'));
}
public function getName() { return 'ads_linkbundle_link'; }
}
```

What I need to figure out, is when creating a link, I need to also be able to create the correct path and weight to go with it.  The paths won't be in the database before a link is created.

Here is what I have for my controller:

```
 public function newAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Link();
    $form = $this->createForm(new LinkType(), $entity);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $code = $this->get('ads.default');
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $entity->setDateAdded(new \DateTime("now"));
            $entity->setCreatedBy($user);
            $entity->setSlug($code->generateToken(5));
            $entity->setCompany($user->getParentCompany());
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            return new Response(json_encode(array('error' => '0', 'success' => '1')));
        }
        return new Response(json_encode(array('error' => count($form->getErrors()), 'success' => '0')));
    }

    return $this->render('ADSLinkBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'saction' => $this->generateUrl('ads.link.new'),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the question is very clear. You need to know how to create the path and weight, but you are not telling us where the information will come from. If this information comes from the request, and the forms and entities are setup correctly you should be able to create or edit collection (related entities) using the form. Take a look at the Symfony documentation [How to embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) for more info.

Comment: I am telling you where the information will come from actually.  It will come from the form, though because I haven't done this before the form is incomplete. Looking for guidance on how to have my Links form, include the ability to also create multiple 'paths'.

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted on my fist comment. The docs walk you through on how to add multiple tags to a task. Your problem is similar, you need to add multiple paths to a link, right? you may need a additional form type for the path and add it to the link as a collection.

Comment: That helped a lot...  Only problem i'm having now is the relationship.  Link is a onetomany to paths, and paths is a manytoone to link.  When I submit the form, it inserts everything but the link id isnt stored on the paths table.  Perhaps I have the relationship wrong.  I edited the question, to fit with the new changes.

Comment: Figured it out.  On my form, I had to add `'by_reference' => false` and modify the `addPath()` method in my `Link Entity`

Comment: Great! can you post the answer? That way we know exactly what you did!

Comment: Yep.  I am having another little issue, maybe you can point me to the right path... in my view for the form i use:

`<div class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.paths.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        </div>`

as on the link you provided, but the html it generates needs to be modified some how and i'm not sure exactly how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Onema ( read the comments above ), I've figured this out.  By reading the documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html  It gave me information I needed to get this done.

First step in doing what I needed to do, was to create a new `form type` called `PathsType.php` which houses the fields associated with the `Paths Entity`

```
<?php
namespace ADS\LinkBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PathType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('pathAddress')
        ->add('pathWeight')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Path'));
}
public function getName() { return 'ads_linkbundle_path'; }
}
```

Then modifying the `LinkType.php` to utilize this new form

```
<?php
namespace ADS\LinkBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class LinkType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('designator')
        ->add('domain', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ADS\DomainBundle\Entity\Domain',
            'property' => 'domainAddress'
        ))
        ->add('paths', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new PathType(), 
                 'allow_add' => true,))
        ->add('Submit', 'submit')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Link'));
}
public function getName() { return 'ads_linkbundle_link'; }
}
```

The addition of `allow_add` makes it so that you can add multiple instances of that form.

Within the view, I now utilize the `data-prototype` attribute.  In the documentation, it has the example using a list item - so that's where I started.

`<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.paths.vars.prototype)|e }}"></ul>`

Then came the jQuery functions ( listed on the documentation link above, simple copy/paste will work )

This got the system working, with 1 small issue and that in my `paths entity`, I have a relationship to the `Link entity` but it was not noticing this relationship and had the `link_id` field as `null`

To combat this, we edit `LinkType.php` one more time, and add `by_reference = false` to the `collection` definition.  We then edit the `addPath` method inside the entity to look like so:

```
public function addPath(\ADS\LinkBundle\Entity\Path $paths)
{
    $paths->setLink($this);
    $this->paths->add($paths);
}
```

This sets the current link object, as the link the path is associated with.

At this point, the system is working flawlessly.  It's creating everything that it needs to, only need to adjust the display a little bit.  I personally opted to use a `twig macro` to modify the html output contained in `data-prototype`

my macro as it currently sits (incomplete - but working ) which I added to the beginning of my form.html.twig

```
{% macro path_prototype(paths) %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            {{ form_widget(paths.pathAddress, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'form-control required' }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

In the `HTML` for the form itself, I removed the `list` creation, and replaced it with:

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.paths,'Destination(s)', { 'label_attr' : {'class' : 'col-md-12 control-label align-left text-left' }}) }}
        <div class="tags" data-prototype="{{ _self.path_prototype(form.paths.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I then modified my javascript to use the `div` as a starting point instead of the `ul` in the example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $collectionHolder;

    // setup an "add a tag" link
    var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link btn btn-xs btn-success">Add Another Destination</a>');
    var $newLinkLi = $('<div></div>').append($addTagLink);

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
        $collectionHolder = $('div.tags');

        // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

        // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
        // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);
        addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);

        $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
            // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
            e.preventDefault();

            // add a new tag form (see next code block)
            addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
    });

    function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
        // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
        var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

        // get the new index
        var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

        // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
        // instead be a number based on how many items we have
        var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
        // increase the index with one for the next item
        $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
        console.log(index);
        if (index == 1) {
            console.log('something');
            $('a.add_tag_link').remove();
        }
        // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
        var $newFormLi = newForm;
        $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    }
</script>
```

Being that these `paths` are destination addresses for an A/B split test within my marketing app, I opted to limit the paths to 2 per link.  And with this, I have successfully setup a form to use a `collections` type.